# $ (x^t v_1) (x^t v_2) (x^t v_3) = x^t A x$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a 3x3 matrix A, is there always a solution for $v_1, v_2, v_3$ to $ (x^t v_1) (x^t v_2) (x^t v_3) = x^t A x$ over a field $F$ with $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ and $x$ being vectors of length 3, with $A$ being a given and the equation needs to be correct for all $x$s?

How could you find that solution when it exists?

Comment: What do you mean by $x^t v_1 x^2 v_2 x^3 v_3$ and $xAx^t$. A $3 \times 3$ matrix is not compatible for left multiplication by a 3-dimensional vector? Do you mean $x^t A x$?

Comment: yes, sorry. I fixed it now.

Comment: The product (?) $x^t v_1 x^2 v_2 x^3 v_3$ is still not clear. If these are, as you say, all vectors, this product is not well defined. $x^t v_1$ gives a scalar since you multiply a $1 \times 3$ with a $3 \times 1$, and $x^2$ has no meaning.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I must have typed $x^2$ and $x^3$ instead of $x^t$ in both of them. Fixed now.

Comment: The left hand side has degree $3$, the right hand side has degree $2$. (Assuming what you try to write is $(x^t v_1)(x^t v_2)(x^t v_3).$

Comment: Shouldn't both sides be a scalar? since $x^t v_n$ is a scalar their multiplication should also be a scalar...

Comment: Since you ask the existence of a solution for $x$, you can regard $x$ as a vector of variables, say $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3).$ Then, the left hand side is the product of $3$ linear functions and the right hand side is a ternary quadric.

Comment: Since I'm stupid, I forgot to say I'm looking for a solution for $v_1, v_2, v_3$...

Comment: Are you saying the matrix $A$ and the vector $x$ is fixed? Or do you mean $A$ is fixed, and we need to find $v_1,v_2,v_3$ such that the equation holds for all $x$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117036/discussion-between-levent-and-command-master).